# Launch an executable and send signal to it whilst running

Tags: bash, signals

I need a script that runs 'A' and send to it a signal that should terminate it, and I need to iterate that with different signals so what I want basically is

```
Launch A ->
send signal S to terminate A and check stuff ->
Relaunch A ->
send signal S1 ......
```

My problem is that in A I've a loop like:

```
while(1){
    scanf()
    ...DO STUFF...
}
```

So using a script like

```
./A arguments
kill -s QUIT A'sPid
```

won't work, because obviously it will not reach the kill line until A's over, and it won't without a signal or user input.

Can you give me any hint? Thanks, and sorry if it's a banal question, but I've just started learning this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the `A` instance into the background (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process)), so that as it runs you can do something else, namely, send it a signal using `kill`.

To background a process put an `&` at the end, i.e.:

```
./A arguments &
```

Once the background process is started the script will move on to the next command.

Answer (score 2):

```
SIGNAL=yourSignal
while [ condition ] ; do
   ./a.out &
   PID=$!
   kill -s $SIGNAL $PID
done
```

Comment: kill requires the PID of the process to which it should send the signal. In `bash` the PID of the last backgrounded process can be obtained via the variable `$!`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers oh yeah.. duh :)